# What is a good choice for Fulltext indexing when developing a OSX application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, full-text-search, macruby, full-text-indexing

Hy,

I'm implementing an IMAP client as a Mac OSX application using MacRuby.
For the sake of offline availability, I wanted to allow fulltext indexing and attribute based indexing of all messages. Attributes include common E-Mail stuff like from:, to:, etc...
This would allow for advanced results sprinkled with faceting, analytic calculations and such.

Now I'm unsure about the choices and good practices when it comes to integrating such a search feature. I have a strong web development background, therefore my intuitive action would be to setup a Solr server and start feeding it with data. This might just work *theoretically*, as I could write an *Agent* that manages the solr instance for my application in the background. But to me, this approach seems like an infrastructure hassle.

On the other side, I've read about people using the *FTS3* functionality from *SQLite*. This approach is easily accessible by *CoreData*. I haven't used *SQLite's FTS3* but I don't think it is as powerful as Solr can be.

**What is your weapon of choice for a use case like mine?**

I'm mainly interested in solutions that are actually in use by Objective-C/Cocoa/MacRuby developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you're going to develop the app with Ruby give a try to [picky](http://florianhanke.com/picky/). It is very simple to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen its presentation at EuRuKo 2010 Krakow. That thing is definitely one of the most amazing stunts written in Ruby I've seen so far.

Comment: It took some small effort to get it running on MacRuby. But thanks to the very helpful maintainer Florian Hanke, it is now working on MacRuby. https://github.com/floere/picky/issues/56

Answer (score 0):

There is an Objective-C Lucene port

http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/etoile/trunk/Etoile/Frameworks/LuceneKit/

I have not used it, but in your situation, I'd at least check it out.  In my experience, SQL based full text search can't compete with Lucene, but haven't tried SQLite for this.

EDIT: just noticed the ruby tag -- this started out as port of Lucene

https://github.com/dbalmain/ferret